# Beginner level:I have started R two weeks back and I am learning function now but I could not understand the below mentioned code at all

Tags: r

```
 n<-2

 make.power<-function(n) {
    pow<-function(x)
    x^n
 }
```

Here n is a free variable. Now I called the pow function 
pow(2)
instead of giving me the square , error is showing that pow function does not exist. Help me out where am I wrong

Comment: You are missing a left brace `{` which should follow `pow<-function(x)`.

Comment: `pow` cannot be found in the global environment because it is inside `make.power`.  A function's body is its own environment.  Furthermore, it is never used inside `make.power`, only defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not know what x value is.
Here

is the easy way:
pow <- function (x,n) x^n  # then on new line pow(3,2)

Comment: This is not quite the question being asked. It's not how to create a function that returns `x^n` but one that returns the function `function(x) x^n`.